# Não consigo restaurar o meu backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup

Fiz um backup certa vez e deu tudo certo. Agora foram criadas mais tabelas, views w wtc e preciso atualizar o banco. Como o banco fica em um endereço da rede e por segurança, não temos como fazer qualquer coisa, o gestor aqui fez um backup para eu instalar em meu localhost e poder trampar em casa. Bem, não consigo restaurar. Da esse erro sempre, quando opto por dispositivo. Veja o erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se opto por Banco de Dados, dá esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que passa é eu não consigo limpar a área, ou seja, já adicionei outro backup, com outro nome, mas ele sempre busca o antigo. Como eu faço?

Comment: Primeira pergunta: esse backup que o gestor fez é consistente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pnet, tenta clicar com o botão direito no banco de dados e selecionando a **Opções**.

Daí dentro do grupo **Estado** você muda o **Acesso restrito** para `SINGLE_USER`

Então é só fazer a restauração novamente.

Segue imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Pnet, para a primeira tela, o erro informa que sua tentativa de acesso exclusivo, não foi possível. Isso acontece, quanto há uma ou mais sessões abertas, no banco que você tenta sobrescrever. Uma forma simples e rápida de descobrir se existe, é rodar o comando abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE dbid = DB_ID('[nome_base]')
```

Importante: Você não pode ter nenhuma sessão aberta, seja por driver, seja por sessão do Management Studio.

Caso tenha alguma sessão aberta, mate com um `kill <spid`

Para a segunda tela, o erro é bem tranquilo. Ele simplesmente diz que, o arquivo de backup que está tentando usar, não foi localizado (erro 2 do Sistema Operacional).

Retorna depois, dizendo se conseguiu restaurar ou não a base.